# How can i get url parameters on VF page that is in communities?

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning-community, community-builder

I have a community page and VF page is embedded. When I try to access url parameters using {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id} or even in the apex controller, it won't work.

That same page will render the url parameters when in sites. What is stopping the access and how can i change it?

My code is visualforce page parameters {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id} in a VF page. I put the url as /pagename?id=123455

It shows when using as sites but does not show when vf page in communities.

Comment: So you have a VF Page dragged into a lightning community page, is this correct?

Comment: @GlenDeMarcos Yes. I put the same VF on Sites and it works without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Visualforce Page` renders inside an `iframe` in communities, I decided to get parameters using the js script block:

```
<script>
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.parent.location.search);
        // Get a specific parameter value
        const maticha = urlParams.get('maticha');
        // Use the parameter value in your code
        console.log(maticha);
</script>
```